# Why am I getting the Aggregate Function error with the following SELECT?

Tags: group-by, counting, having

I'm attempting to count the number of instances of a value that includes "WMH" and then sort the result (like a "Top 10 Most Popular" list). But I am getting the aggregate function error.

Any thoughts about this:

```
SELECT TrackingLabel, Count(TrackingLabel) AS CountOfTrackingLabel
FROM CTM_Export
GROUP BY TrackingLabel
HAVING TrackingLabel Like 'WMH'
```

Comment: BTW, this works in MS Access but when I translate it into Classic ASP/ADO it generates the error.

Answer (score 1):

Having clause  refers to the same columns/aggregate functions used in select list, for example

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING aggregate_function(column_name) operator value;
```

with regards to your query, if I understand your requirements, you could rewrite the query like:

```
SELECT TrackingLabel, Count(TrackingLabel) AS CountOfTrackingLabel
FROM CTM_Export
WHERE TrackingLabel Like 'WMH'
GROUP BY TrackingLabel;
```

regards, Michael

Comment: Ok, newb question... how do I add additional columns to the SELECT? (getting "Item cannot be found in the collection" error now with a field named "TrackingBusiness")

Comment: Michael, your suggestion worked btw. Just need to add more columns to it now.